# Weak solution of SDE with tanh drift

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to find a solution (either weak or strong) of following SDE:

$$
\mathrm{d}X_t = \tanh(X_t) \ \mathrm{d}t + \mathrm{d}W_t, 
$$
where $W_t$ denotes the Wiener process.

**My Attempt:**

I tried to use the Girsanov theorem (similar to the post in [Link](https://stevensoojin.kim/blog/weak-solutions/)) to find a weak solution and I got stuck at evaluating the following integral:
$$
W_t = X_t - X_0 - \int_0^t \tanh(X_s) \ \mathrm{d}s.
$$

This is the Riemannian integral but it also has $X_s$ therefore, I am confused.

I am new to this area so any ideas or pointers to any books are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You want an [explicit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Some_explicitly_solvable_SDEs%5B4%5D) solution ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have $X_t$ in terms of $X_0$ and the Wiener process $W_t$ if possible.

Comment: $tanh$ is Lipschitz, thus there exists a unique solution. I would not (or better never) expect an explicit solution.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I can ask, when can we find an explicit solution of $dX_t = b(X_t, t) dt + dW_t$? I know if $b(X_t, t)$ is constant or linear in $X_t$, then we can find the explicit solution. For what other $b(X_t, t)$ we can find the solution?

Comment: The link I gave in my earlier comment is quite exhaustive. A way to find explicit solutions is to make the ansatz $X_t=f(t,W_t)$ , then use Ito and match the derivatives terms to the functions in your SDE. This leads to a system of PDEs for $f$. For $\tanh(X_t)$ it would surprise me if that works. What is the context of that question ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the link and I also checked the Kloeden & Platten's book on numerical solution of stochastic differential equations for more exhaustive list but I still could not find any other function $b(X_t, t)$ for which there exist an explicit solution.  

My motivation behind the question was to find explicitly solvable SDEs with constant (or independent of $X_t$) diffusion matrix. I know that if the drift matrix is linear in $X_t$ or independent of $X_t$, then we can find the explicit solution but I do not know any other case.

Comment: I even tried using ito's lemma but I am not able to find it. I think this is difficult because suppose $X_t$ is a process generated using $dX_t = b(X_t, t)dt + dW_t$. Now, the process $Y_t$ (generated by $Y_t = f(X_t, t)$) might transform the SDE of $X_t$ into a form which is explicitly solvable by some other transformation(Let's say by using $Z_t = g(Y_t, t)$). Then some composition of $f$ and $g$ (and their inverses) will give another explicitly solvable SDE.